# The Longest Word Made from Chemical Symbols

Tags: word, open-ended

So, as you probably know, each and every element in the [Periodic Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table) has its own unique *chemical symbol*, which is either one, two, or three letters long. For instance, Oxygen is represented as **O** and Copper as **Cu**. So how about combining these symbols to form words?

For instance, **Ba**rium and **N**eo**d**ymium would give us **Band**, or **C**h**l**orine-**Am**ericium-**P**hosphorus would give us **Clamp**. So how long can these words get? I've managed the following examples:

> **Br**omine-**O**xygen-**C**arbon-**Co**balt-**Li**thium: **Broccoli** (8)
>
> **B**oron-**I**odine-**C**arbon-**Y**ttrium-**C**h**l**orine-**E**in**s**teinium: **Bicycles** (8)
>
> **Th**orium-**U**ranium-**N**eo**d**ymium-**Er**bium-**O**xygen-**U**ranium-**S**ulphur: **Thunderous** (10)

So, community, can you beat my attempts? For clarification, I will allow any word on [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/), including alternate forms of the word (plurals, verb conjugations, etc.). The word must be constructed using only chemical symbols that are recognised according to the Wikipedia page. You may use any symbol as many times as you like in your word.

Victory will go to the person who can give the longest word in characters, *not* the word made from the most symbols.

Comment: Is there a restriction you want to add that each symbol used only once?

Comment: @skv My best entry (Thunderous) uses Uranium (U) twice, so that will not be a restriction.

Comment: In some musics, the singer sings "Nananana-nanana-na-na-na-na-na-na-nananana...", Does this counts as "Sodium-Sodium-Sodium-Sodium-Sodium..."?

Comment: :) I really like the idea, but Thats not on dictionary.com I guess @Victor

Comment: Related (and amusing): [a list of elements spelled with elements](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~haltman/elements.txt)

Comment: @Victor Post edited, meant to put Phosphorus, thank you

Comment: Are D for deuterium and T for tritium, both hydrogen isotopes, allowed? What about A, the former symbol for argon, and Cb, the former symbol for niobium?

Comment: I think my answer was accepted by mistake, though this is the highest voted, there is a candidate with longer word

Comment: @skv Ah yes, my mistake. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Not a winner, but I wanted to point out: sulfur uranium phosphorus erbium calcium lithium francium silver iodine lithium sulfur titanium carbon, spells SUPErCaLiFrAgILiSTiC.

Comment: You should re-write this puzzle to not have repeated elements to make it harder for the winner :P.

Comment: This should be called the "Breaking Bad Title Sequence" puzzle. :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

One of my favourite words, that's 29 characters long is:

> [Floccinaucinihilipilification](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/floccinaucinihilipilification?s=t) - the estimation of something as being worthless.

It's quite useful for describing what the contestants find on a fair few reality TV programmes! As most of the letters are covered off by only a few elements there's quite a lot of repetition...

> Fl - Flerovium
> O - Oxygen
> C - Carbon
> C - Carbon
> I - Iodine
> N - Nitrogen
> Au - Gold
> C - Carbon
> I - Iodine
> N - Nitrogen
> I - Iodine
> H - Hydrogen
> I - Iodine
> Li - Lithium
> P - Phosphorus
> I - Iodine
> Li - Lithium
> F - Fluorine
> I - Iodine
> C - Carbon
> At - Astatine
> I - Iodine
> O - Oxygen
> N - Nitrogen

Comment: Nooooo I started posting this answer 7 minutes ago but I couldn't figure out spoiler markup!

Comment: If it makes you feel any better I had to go to the shops before they closed, otherwise I'd have posted it half an hour ago @Mack :-)... and I think you still got in there first!

Comment: crap, that's long

Comment: Couldn't you have used floccinaucinihilipilificatiousness instead?  It's 33 letters.

Answer (score 33):

Perhaps this is cheating, but my answer (inspired by the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_word_in_English#Humour) on the longest English words) is

> YArDs

Formed by

> Yttrium, Argon, Darmstadtium

Note:

> This word is, of course, much shorter than any other words given so far. The reason, though, that it's longer is that it's a yard long.

Comment: Um... You do realize that the OP gives at least three words that exceed 5 characters in length?

Comment: @COTO Of course. It's a joke - none of the words given are longer than a yard.

Comment: @HDE Really depends on the font being used ;)

Comment: @Voo True. . . .

Comment: +1 for thinking outside the box (although PArSeC is much longer) (oh, TeRaPArSeC).

Comment: *groaaan* OK. +1 because you got me.

Comment: Maybe we could go with InFInITe then?

Comment: Or INFINITe @Psychemaster :-).

Answer (score 24):

> nonrepresentationalisms (23 characters is the maximum that can be formed) 
> as 
>
>
> No+N+Re+P+Re+Se+N+Ta+Ti+O+Na+Li+Sm+S
>
> Nobelium+Nitrogen+Rhenium+Phosphorus+Rhenium+Selenium+Nitrogen+Tantalum+Titanium+Oxygen+Sodium+Lithium+Samarium+Sulphur

There is a word

> hypothalamicohypophyseal

which is not listed in every dictionary which has 24 characters

If only unique usage (each element being used once is a condition) then

> There is a tie "hypercoagulabilities" and "hyperconsciousnesses" ("HYPErCoAgULaBiLiTiEs" and "HYPErCoNScIOUSnEsSeS") - 20 characters

My Source

> Google which led to
> http://www.nandor.org/math/chemwords/chemwords.htm

Comment: Ah... I guess that may be a problem with this puzzle.

Comment: :) Thats a problem with any puzzle on this site

Comment: I have added the names just to ensure there is some value add

Comment: I feel like google was a bit of a cheat, but +1 for facts.

Comment: @skv: here's your 23 letter word too: http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/december12012/index.html

Answer (score 21):

29 characters

> floccinaucinihilipilification
>  Fl O C C I N Au C I N I H I Li P I Li F I C At I O N
>  114, the atomic number of Flerovium, is the highest one used so far

Answer (score 20):

I wrote a script (http://pastebin.com/T60RQdXa) that takes a wordlist and outputs the largest word that can be written as a concatenation of chemical symbols. Calling `python chemWords.py /usr/share/dict/words` yields "NoNRePReSeNTaTiONAl" (19 chars). Calling with a more complete dictionary gives "FlOCCINAuCINIHILiPILiFICAtIONS" (30 chars).

Comment: The rules actually allow plural, so this is currently the highest scoring answer.

Comment: Incidentally I also turned to programming and wrote a really bare-bones C# program and a regex. And yes, the regex is stupidly long, but it does work.

Answer (score 17):

Placing the emphasis on "the longest word **made** from chemical symbols" - embroidery on a bag!

(From https://secure.flickr.com/photos/rjw76/15497828388/ )

[image: PuFFeRfISH Bag]

Answer (score 4):

Ben and andrepd already came up with the longest, FlOCCINaUCINIHILiPILiFICAtION (or its plural, FlOCCINaUCINIHILiPILiFICAtIONS)—though note that this word was made possible only recently by IUPAC's adoption in 2012 of "Fl" as the symbol for flerovium.  Before 2012, the longest word would have been the 23-letter NONRePReSeNTaTiONAlISmS, as reported by skv.

Incidentally, it's interesting to consider what happens if we restrict ourselves to one- or two-letter element symbols.  For one-letter symbols, there is one 14-letter example:

> PSYCHOPANNYCHY

Or if repeated symbols are forbidden:

> WICKYUPS, UNBISHOP, CUSHIONY, CHIBOUKS, BOYCHIKS

For two-letter symbols, there is the following 18-letter example:

> IrRePrEsSiBiLiTiEs

Or if repeated symbols are forbidden:

> ThErMoLaBiLiTiEs, IrRePaRaBiLiTiEs, InSePaRaBiLiTiEs, InAlTeRaBiLiTiEs

The above examples are taken from the *[Word Ways](http://www.wordways.com/)* article ["Elemental Words Revisited"](http://digitalcommons.butler.edu/wordways/vol47/iss4/22/).  That article (along with a follow-up by Darryl Francis, ["King's Moves in the Periodic Table"](http://digitalcommons.butler.edu/wordways/vol48/iss1/13/)) also describes many other types of words formed from the chemical symbols, such as the longest words whose symbols are in increasing or decreasing order of atomic number, the longest words for each group or period in the periodic table, the words which can be spelled the most different ways, etc.

Comment: +1 for answering these variations of the original question, and for the citation.

Answer (score 3):

A pretty common word with 20 characters, in British spelling:

> **internationalisation** 
>  
>  **I**odine-**N**itrogen-**Te**llurium-**R**ado**n**-**A**sta**t**ine-**I**odine-**O**xygen-**N**itrogen-**Al**uminum-**I**odine-**S**ulfur-**A**sta**t**ine-**I**odine-**O**xygen-**N**itrogen

Comment: That's more like I18N

Comment: @SztupY I18N would be Iodine-Argon-Nitrogen.

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly not as long as other answers, and the optimal answer appears to have been posted, but I've always liked:

> ThErMoDyNAmICs

Which is...

> Thorium, erbium, molybdenum, dysprosium, nitrogen, americium, iodine, cesium (alternatively carbon and sulphur)