# The Longest Word Made from Specific Chemical Symbols

Tags: word, open-ended

So, my [first question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5456/the-longest-word-made-from-chemical-symbols/) on this topic was answered fairly quickly with quite a long word, so I thought I might post a different version of the puzzle

The idea this time is similar to last time: you must construct the longest possible word from *chemical symbols* on the [Periodic Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table). However this time, to narrow down the playing field a little, I've restricted the chemical symbols that can be used in your word into 7 categories:

> 1 - Alkali Metals and Alkali Earth Metals + Hydrogen;
>   H, Li, Be, Na, Mg, K, Ca, Rb, Sr, Cs, Ba, Fr, Ra
>
> 2 - Transition Metals;
>   Sc, Ti, V, Cr, Mn, Fe, Co, Ni, Cu, Zn, Y, Zr, Nb, Mo, Tc, Ru, Rh, Pd, Ag, Cd, Hf, Ta, W, Re, Os, Ir, Pt, Au, Hg, Rf, Db, Sg, Bh, Hs, Mt, Ds, Rg, Cn
>
> 3 - *Groups* 3 + 4 (Groups topped with Boron / Carbon);
>   B, C, Al, Si, Ga, Ge, In, Sn, Tl, Pb, Uut, Fl
>
> 4 - *Groups* 5 + 6 (Groups topped with Nitrogen / Oxygen);
>   N, O, P, S, As, Se, Sb, Te, Bi, Po, Uup, Lv
>
> 5 - The *Halogens* and *Noble Gases*;
>   He, F, Ne, Cl, Ar, Br, Kr, I, Xe, At, Rn, Uus, Uuo
>
> 6 - The *Lanthanides*;
>   La, Ce, Pr, Nd, Pm, Sm, Eu, Gd, Tb, Dy, Ho, Er, Tm, Yb, Lu
>
> 7 - The *Actinides*;
>   Ac, Th, Pa, U, Np, Pu, Am, Cm, Bk, Cf, Es, Fm, Md, No, Lr

Simply answer any or all of these categories with the longest possible word made from that particular groups of elements. May the games begin!

Comment: Can you provide a list of elements we can use? I have a list but I don't know what ones fall in what category...

Comment: @warspyking Figuring that out is part of the puzzle!

Comment: The lanthanides and actinides are going to be doozies - most of the abbreviations are two letters.

Comment: @HDE226868, I'm not sure whether doozies are easy or hard, but far more important than being one or two letters is what vowels are available.

Comment: @PeterTaylor - They're hard.

Comment: @warspyking I didn't anticipate that this would cause confusion, but it seems people are considering the groups 3 to 6 to being within the transition metals... I meant the groups topped with elements Boron through Oxygen. The post has been edited for clarification.

Comment: Why not clarify properly as requested by warspyking and upvoted by four people (including myself)? If you provide a complete list for each of the seven categories then it becomes a much better question.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I will do that now, should've done it originally

Comment: Sorry everyone about the lack of clarification in the question, I'm still a newbie to the site :P

Comment: @ForIInRange. Halogens/Nobel Gases has **Kr** twice and **Xe** is missing.

Comment: @ekhumoro corrected

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019

Comment: This one seems restricted enough to be a fairly bounded puzzle; I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All words are in SOWPODS.

1. *CaRaCaRa*
2. *CrOsTiNi* (NB using the red-background elements from [the first table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_metal#Classification) in the Wikipedia article: the article notes that there isn't universal agreement on what the term means).
3. *AlGeSiC*
4. *TeAsPoONS*
5. *HeXeNe*
6. *LaNdLaDy*
7. *AmEsAcEs*

Comment: 4. Can do with Tamo

Comment: @skv, not in SOWPODS.

Comment: But the OP wanted words in dictionary.com so technically its acceptable for this Question I guess

Comment: Answers 1, 2, 5 and 6 are great, but when I said groups 3-4 and 5-6 I meant the groups topped with Boron-Oxygen. I guess wikipedia uses that method of group counting... the post has been edited for clarification but well done, the best all-round attempt so far.

Answer (score 4):

I'll start the ball rolling. I don't know if these are the longest. I'd be happy to be proven wrong. NB: I got all the lists of elements from Wikipedia.

- *Alkali metals and alkaline earth metals*: "BaNaNa"
- *Transition metals*: "ScReWY" (there *must* be something longer than this)
- *Group 3 and 4*: "LaY"
- *Group 5 and 6*: "MoW"
- *Halogens and noble gases*: "BrIAr"
- *Lanthanides*: "LaNdLaDy"
- *Actinides*: "ThEsEs"

Comment: Ba is not an alakali metal nor is it H.

Comment: but it is Alkaline Earth metal I guess

Comment: You're right! My bad!

Answer (score 2):

1 Alkali Metals and Alkali Earth Metals + Hydrogen:

> Barabara [BaRaBaRa] (8)
>  Caracara [CaRaCaRa] (8)
>  Banana [BaNaNa] (6)
>  Cabana [CaBaNa] (6)
>  Linacs [LiNaCs] (6)

2 Transition Metals:

> Crostini [CrOsTiNi] (8)
>  Redbirds [ReDbIrDs] (8)
>  Cryptos [CrYPtOs] (7)
>  Viragos [VIrAgOs] (7)

3 Groups 3 + 4 (Groups topped with Boron / Carbon):

> Albinal [AlBInAl] (7)
>  Algesic [AlGeSiC] (7)

4 Groups 5 + 6 (Groups topped with Nitrogen / Oxygen):

> Nonsenses [NONSeNSeS] (9)
>  Possesses [POSSeSSeS] (9)
>  Teaspoons [TeAsPoONS] (9)
>  Assesses [AsSeSSeS] (8)
>  Nonsense [NONSeNSe] (8)
>  Osteoses [OSTeOSeS] (8)
>  Sponsons [SPONSONS] (8)
>  Stenoses [STeNOSeS] (8)
>  Stepsons [STePSONS] (8)

5 The Halogens and Noble Gases:

> Hexene [HeXeNe] (6)
>  Neinei [NeINeI] (6)
>  Briar [BrIAr] (5)
>  Brine [BrINe] (5)
>  Cliff [ClIFF] (5)
>  Cline [ClINe] (5)

6 The Lanthanides:

> Landlady [LaNdLaDy] (8)
>  Lander [LaNdEr] (6)

7 The Actinides:

> Amesaces [AmEsAcEs] (8)
>  Estheses [EsThEsEs] (8)
>  Noeses [NoEsEs] (6)
>  Theses [ThEsEs] (6)

Answer (score 0):

For the alkali metals et. al., CaBaNa is the best I can do.

BrINe ties BrIAr for the longest I can find in the halogens and noble gases.