# What is the longest word made from Chemical Symbols without repeats?

Tags: word

I guess as an addendum to [The Longest Word Made from Chemical Symbols](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5456/the-longest-word-made-from-chemical-symbols)

What is the longest word in the ENGLISH language that can be formed by combining chemical symbols and has no repeat elements in its name?

Comment: This question should be [considered a duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3023/202205), since it is already answered in [another question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/5457/4450).

Comment: @pacoverflow Unfortunately it's not, just because an answer addresses the facet. If you read the other question carefully, you'll see that the OP specifically mentioned repeats are allowed.

Comment: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5456/the-longest-word-made-from-chemical-symbols#comment16477_5456

Comment: But if you read my second link, that answer also includes the case when you limit it to once per element.

Comment: @pacoverflow Like I said, there's no way to see if that answer is truly correct, since other answers are all geared towards the "as many elements as you'd like" rule.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not in agreement with the duplicate flags - the goals of both questions do differ, it just happens to be that some of the answers to the linked question also cover cases where there is no repetition of elements in the word.

Comment: @Psychemaster if this part were to be fully answered in that question (intentionally or otherwise) then there is merit to close this for new answers while retaining the question as a duplicate (closed), but we are still finding out so I guess at this stage calling it a duplicate is not correct

Comment: I posted the original question as a sort of introduction to a topic of questions along these lines of using Chemical Symbols to make words, I think that it's fine for @thinlyveiledquestionmark to use this idea, along with anyone else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To ensure that we dont search something less than 20 charaters I am posting this

If only unique usage (each element being used once is a condition) then

> [There is a tie](http://www.nandor.org/math/chemwords/chemwords.htm) between "hypercoagulabilities" and "hyperconsciousnesses" ("HYPErCoAgULaBiLiTiEs" and "HYPErCoNScIOUSnEsSeS") - both are 20 characters

In case if this is found as the valid answer in a reasonable amount of time, then yes this question can be considered duplicate (but not deleted)

To ensure that I dont get credits for copying and pasting and in the true sense this is community wiki's primary purpose as per me, I am marking it as community wiki