# Open-ended challenge: Find the longest morsagram word pair

Tags: word, open-ended

The idea for this challenge stems from [this posting on ComputerScience (beta)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/34067/is-morse-code-without-spaces-uniquely-decipherable).

---

It is established (see [above link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/34067/is-morse-code-without-spaces-uniquely-decipherable)), that Morse-code requires the 'space' between individual character to be uniquely decipherable.

The answer of [Aaron Dufour](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/20068/aaron-dufour) there defines the term **morsagram** as a pair of messages which, encoded in morse code become *identical* if the spaces are left out. His provided example is:

> `SPACES` = | `...` | `.--.` | `.-` | `-.-.` | `.` | `...` | = **`....--..--.-.....`** 
> and
> `SWITCH` = | `...` | `.--` | `..` | `-` | `-.-.` | `....` | = **`....--..--.-.....`**

### I now challenge to find the longest *morsagram* pair of words in English.

To remove ambiguity, and in analogy to [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5456/the-longest-word-made-from-chemical-symbols/5457#5457), all English words which appear on  [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/) are permitted.

You may only use the Morse-code equivalents for the 26 characters of the [international Morse code table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:International_Morse_Code.svg).

As consequence of the rule above: solutions are case-insensitive. Use capital letters for all.

Also: The two words of the *morsagram* may be of different length when written in English.

---

**The winning condition is to find the *longest* words** (sum of both lengths of the English words).

**A bonus is to find the most *interesting* pair**. This, of course, is highly subjective. Interesting may be one of the following: *most different characters*;  *opposite meaning*; two very *common* but otherwise *unrelated* words; words with have another *surprising* connection...

**A second bonus question is to find the most *interesting sentences* which are morsograms**. 
Again, an example is already provided in the linked posting above:

> `SOS HELP`      = |`...`|`---`|`...`|`....`|`.`|`.-..`|`.--.`| = **`...---.........-...--.`**
> and
> `I AM HIS DATE` = |`..`|`.-`|`--`|`....`|`..`|`...`|`-..`|`.-`|`-`|`.`| = **`...---.........-...--.`**

For this bonus-question, disregards punctuation in the Morse-code.

I will *accept* and *un-accept* answers for the winning condition as new records are brought in. 

**Up-votes** should be given to answers which you believe fulfil the bonus condition.

Comment: Are [prosigns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosigns_for_Morse_code) allowed? [Q codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_code)?  [Morse abbrevs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code_abbreviations)?

Comment: Do you want us to refrain from writing code? Otherwise, it's fairly simple to brute force.

Comment: already brute-forced it for like 2 min (code-writing included)

Comment: @xnor The means you use to arrive at the solution is free to choose. I'm really interested in the **result(s)** here - also to be used at later time for other puzzles (not on this sits ;c)) If you do a brute-force technique, fine go ahead. (In fact, the provided link on top is a useful starting point.) However, the *solution* should not be code, it should be the morsagram(s) as in the example above. (BTW, there is never a way to prevent people from writing code to solve a puzzle - and many do.)

Comment: Nice contest!  I considered brute-forcing it but hadn't found the time yet.  The linked answer has a link to a pastebin containing code that takes in morse code (without spaces) and returns all possible phrases (based on a given dictionary).  Its fairly easy to modify this to take a phrase and return all morsagrams of that phrase, which makes searching for interesting phrases easier.

Comment: BmyGuest, like the new open-ended tag? Created it myself just then when I saw this question. (Waiting for tag wiki to be approved)

Comment: The follow-up question to this should be the longest possible morse palindrome.

Comment: @No.7892142 Where the morsecode is the same when flipped? I would love to see that.

Comment: @Rik_S Well, as a trivial example take the word "is", aka •••••. Or "wig" aka •--••--•.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Longest word-pair so far:

> **`.--..-..-.-.----.-.--.--.---.-..--..---..-...`**
>  18: [PRECONTEMPORANEOUS](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/PRECONTEMPORANEOUS?s=t)
>  19: [PENECONTEMPORANEOUS](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/PENECONTEMPORANEOUS?s=t)

**Most *interesting pair*:**

> The pairs with greatest difference in length (omitting abr.):
> -.-.-.---.-.: TENTAMEN, CYC, (len 8,3)
> .---.-.-.--.: JAAP, ATTENTATE, (len 4,9)
> -.-.---.--.: COP, TENTMATE, (len 3,4,4,8,4)

**OR**

> ......-.-.-.-.........-........: HURTLESSNESS, HEARTLESSNESS, (len 12, 13)
> Are you hurtless when heartless?

**OR**

> The UNs ..--......--..-.--.: UNSEEMING, UNSEWING, UNSEATING, UNSITTING, UNHATING, (len 9,8,9,9,8)

Brute forced top 20:

> .--..-..-.-.----.-.--.--.---.-..--..---..-...: PRECONTEMPORANEOUS, PENECONTEMPORANEOUS, (len 18,19)
> ....--..-.....---.-..-----...-.-..-.-...-..-.--: SEMITHEOLOGICALLY, SEMIBIOLOGICALLY, (len 17,16)
> .--.....-.--.....-.-.----.....---.-..-----...-.-..-.-..: PHYSICOBIOLOGICAL, PHYSICOTHEOLOGICAL, (len 17,18)
> -.----....-..-...-.--....-...-........: NONIRRITABLENESS, NONVERITABLENESS, (len 16,16)
> ..--.-....--..-.............-.-........: UNDEPRESSIVENESS, UNDIGRESSIVENESS, (len 16,16)
> -.----.-.....---.-..-----...-.-..-.-...-..-.--: NONTHEOLOGICALLY, NONBIOLOGICALLY, (len 16,15)
> .--..-.-.-..-...-....-..--.-.-........--.: PECTINIBRANCHIAN, PECTINIBRANCHIATE, (len 16,17)
> .--...-.....-.-..--.-.....-.---.--...-..: PITHECANTHROPINE, PITHECANTHROPID, (len 16,15)
> -........-.-....-...-.-..--..----.: DESERTIFICATION, DESULFURATION, (len 15,13)
> ..-...-...------....-..--.-.-........--.: ELASMOBRANCHIAN, ELASMOBRANCHIATE, (len 15,16)
> .--..--.....--.--..-.-..-.-...-..-.--: ANATHEMATICALLY, PATHEMATICALLY, (len 15,14)
> ..--....-..-...-.--....-...-........: UNIRRITABLENESS, UNVERITABLENESS, (len 15,15)
> ..--......-.-..--..-.......-..-........: UNSURPRISEDNESS, UNSURPASSEDNESS, (len 15,15)
> -.----....----.-....--....-...-........: NONSOCIABLENESS, NONVOLUBLENESS, (len 15,14)
> -.-..--....--..--.--......-....--.--: TRANSMUTABILITY, TRANSMITTABILITY, (len 15,16)
> ...-.-...--..-....-..--.-.-........--.: SCUTIBRANCHIATE, SCUTIBRANCHIAN, (len 15,14)
> .-..--....-----.-.-...-.-..-.-...-..-.--: AUDIOMETRICALLY, RADIOMETRICALLY, (len 15,15)
> -.-.-..--.-.-..-...-...-....-..: TETRACTINELLINE, TETRACTINELLID, (len 15,14)
> -..--.....-.-....-....-..--.-.-........--.: TUBULIBRANCHIAN, TUBULIBRANCHIATE, (len 15,16)
> .--......-.-.--.--.-.---.--.---......-: PHARMACOPOEIST, PHARMACOPOSIA, (len 14,13)

Don't really care for the up-votes. Just wanted to see if the two words would be of same length.

Comment: Record is 18/19. Edited cause I forgot that some words are in the dictionary both capitalized and not.

Comment: What's the longest word in the dictionary? This will obviously put a cap on the challenge...

Comment: @BmyGuest It's _pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis_. Lovely word, right?

Comment: What dictionary did you use for this?

Comment: Lovely indeed. And the reason why I've restricted this search to **English**. In **German** you can have *endless* composite-words...

Comment: Things do start to get quite meaningless after a while though, but it's quite subjective and would definitely be harder to brute force as it requires some linguistics insight as well.

Comment: Your next challenge is to use all of those words in a sentence.

Comment: @AE I thought about that first, as the linked post provide the nice example of `I AM HIS DATE` being the same as `SOS HELP`, but then I thought that words would do for a start. (And victory condition is more clearly defined.) But maybe you're right, and I'll add that as bonus / 2nd challenge.

Comment: Oh, I just meant that these words are so long and obscure that it would be a challenge to use all of them in a normal English sentence (and have it make sense). :)

Answer (score 19):

Suppose, instead of maximum length or maximum length difference, you care about maximum edit distance (levenshtein). Here are the winners:

```
9 BETTERING DUNLAP -....--..-...-.--.
9 HICCUP HEARTENING ......-.-.-.-...-.--.
9 POLLUTE WAGNERIAN .--.---.-...-....--.
9 RAKING ETIQUETTE .-..--.-..-.--.
9 RANTING ETIQUETTE .-..--.-..-.--.
9 TESTIFIES BLUSH -....-....-.......
9 THINNING DEVASTATE -......-.-...-.--.
```

The longest pair that has no letters in common:

```
THRALL DEFENDED -.....-..-.-...-..
```

Comment: Very nice ones - and very useful for building puzzles. +1

Comment: Nice! This idea can be extended for other [string metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric) as well. The [overlap coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap_coefficient) is particularly interesting as it may be modified to analyse the connection to characters with similar Morse codes.

Comment: I'm curious about the longest pair that has no letters in common.

Comment: @xnor `THRALL DEFENDED`