# A longer chemical word

Tags: word, chemistry

YEs, LuSH CHOCoLaTe CrYPTaNAlYSiS!

...are all English words formed by chaining a string of **distinct**, *standard* [chemical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_elements).

A $19$ character example is IrReCoNCILaBiLiTiEs.

Can you find two examples with more characters? (...or can one of you still find more than two?!)

---

*Note:* [this very similar question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5456/16717) was popular but got closed as too broad, so I have *attempted* to narrow it to a single solution puzzle.

Comment: The solution of other puzzle does not count, does it?

Comment: @AJ the symbols used must be distinct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if I read correctly, one of the other answer still counts here :

> H Y P Er Co N Sc I O U Sn Es Se S (20 letters)
>
>  H Y P Er Co Ag U La Bi Li Ti Es (20 letters)
>
>  Credit to @slv for the answer on the other puzzle.

Comment: Oh, that kind of makes it a duplicate then really :(

Comment: Shouldn't the first one be hyper-consciousness? Why the extra "Es"?

Comment: @Sid It's the plural form!

Comment: lol..... does that even exist??

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hyperconsciousness