# Means of Transportation

Tags: word, chemistry

The answer to this puzzle is a vehicle or a type of transportation. It is created by using simply parts of air, a noble metal and a heavy metal. What is it?

Comment: There's a separate term "noble metal". Nothing much to do with noble gases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: I've found a better fit.

> Wagon:
> W - Tungsten, one of the densest metals in the periodic table
> Ag - Silver, one of the noble metals
> O,N - Oxygen and nitrogen, the two most abundant gases that make up our atmosphere

---

Assume we're spelling things out with chemical symbols, the only thing even close that I've found so far is

> HeLiCOPtEr

But this isn't a perfect fit:

> He and CO can be in the atmosphere, but neither is present in great abundance.
> Li doesn't fit any of the clues.  This is my biggest problem with this answer.
> Pt is a noble metal and fits that clue just fine.
> Er is a metal with a high atomic weight, but it's a lanthanide and not what I'd normally think of if someone says a "heavy metal".

Comment: Joe. That is what I had in mind Wagon. Speaking of Periodic Table what is the longest word you can come up with using only Periodic Table abbreviations?

Comment: Some answers to this question --http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5456/the-longest-word-made-from-chemical-symbols -- are over 20 characters.  I don't think I'm going to beat those.  :-)